Where has the debug button gone in the VS Code CMake Tools bar?
I used to have a debug button like this:

And when I used it, there would be Pause Play Stop commands at the top of the VS Code window.
Since I installed VS Code on a new machine, I only have:

And the Pause Play Stop buttons never appear when I'm running my application.
I have looked in the CMake Tools settings and cannot find anything which helps.
How can I get this functionality back?

This functionality has moved to the sidebar and can be re-added to the bottom bar here:

